# How to calculate touched position of ImageView in ScrollView, Considering Zoom factor?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I have an image that should be click-able in certain areas, say 26 areas in that Image.
What's the best way to do that ?

[image]

I made an image with same size, each click-able area in Image has specific color, with white background, so when the image is clicked, I can get the Pixel color of second image in that position and realize which area is clicked.

The problem is, i need to show picture in `ScrollView`, and image is resized to fit the screen width. I know i can calculate the clicked offset using `event.getRawY() + sv.getScrollY();`, but how to calculate the zoom factor ?

Actually since both images are the same size, i need to calculate the clicked position considering zoom factor to find the precise position of that pixel in second Image.

Comment: You can use the `event.getY()`-method to retrieve the position relative in your View.

Comment: How about zoom factor ?, Original Image is 352*700, but displayed image is stretched to fit the screen width, i need to get the touched position, and scale it to 352*700 basis.

Comment: About the zoom factor.. That is just some math to calculate the correct positions (x,y) depending on the zoom factor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this snipped help you.

```
   @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView1 || v.getId() == R.id.image_scrollview) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX = (int) event.getX();
            startY = (int) event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            int cordinate_Y = (int) ((event.getY() + v.getScrollY()) / diffH);
            int cordinate_X = (int) ((event.getX() + v.getScrollX()) / diffW);
            if ((Math.abs((int) event.getX() - startX) > 10)
                    || (Math.abs((int) event.getY() - startY) > 10)) {
                break;
            }

            int pixelColor = bitmap.getPixel(cordinate_X, cordinate_Y);
            if (pixelColor != -1) {
                showDetails(texts[map.get(pixelColor)],
                        images[map.get(pixelColor)],
                        titles[map.get(pixelColor)]);

            }

            break;

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It actually helped. i had figured it out long before though.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it may be somewhat easier to use `WebView` instead. You can use `<map>` and `<area>` for creating clickable areas and send callbacks to your application using `JavaScript`

Comment: any comments how to do that ?

Comment: Can you please share the example code for the same, using WebView and HTML.